# How to fix broken OpenCL headers

Tags: c++, opencl

I am using the cl.hpp wrapper for OpenCL. I have installed all the required headers and drivers for OpenCL and OpenGL (I am using the AMD ones), but if I try to compile my application it fails, saying:

```
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp Line 1617: undefined reference to 'clReleaseCommandQueue'
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp Line 1608: undefined reference to 'clReleaseContext'
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp Line 2227: undefined reference to 'clGetPlatformIDs'
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp Line 2234: undefined reference to 'clGetPlatformIDs'
```

I searched the internet for a while now but it seams I am the only one having this problem. Do I need to define something? My include code looks like that:

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define USE_CL_DEVICE_FISSION
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is compiling just fine - the errors that you are seeing are linker errors. You just need to link against the OpenCL library (`-lOpenCL` with GCC/Clang, `OpenCL.lib` with MSVC).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I am already linking against OpenCL

Comment: Can you show the command-line that you are using (assuming GCC/Clang)? Some compilers are sensitive to linking order - you may need to make sure that `-lOpenCL` is *after* any object files that use it.

Comment: Never mind: I just was linking against the wrong one. Thanks for the help